# Fill the inside part of characters inside UILabel text with a color (e.g., 'O', 'D', 'R')

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uikit

I need to fill the inside part of some characters of the text in `UILabel` with a color (such as 'O', 'D', 'R' 
and so on). In my case it should be orange color.

Look at the pictures. I need to have this look: [image]   [image]

I suppose it's possible to do such thing using a specific attribute for `NSAttributedString`, but I haven't found it. Do you have any ideas how to implement it? (Swift 3, Objective C)

Thanks!

Comment: "I suppose it's possible to do such thing using a specific attribute for NSAttributedString". I don't think so.

Comment: Maybe you should try to find font with that kind of look.

Comment: @bkrl I thought about it, but I think I won't be able to change color inside the character.

Comment: Of course you can, you can always *create* a custom font for that very use case. But this will probably we a lot of work.

Comment: To explicit a solution by @luk2302: You can have a custom font with let's say "someCharO" and "O", where "someCharO" is the colored part which is a real character, but when you type it, the "cursor" doesn't move. The next char you type will be type over it, that make the illusion. I've encountered font that does that.

Comment: @Larme, thank you!
But I hope I will find a simpler solution :)

Comment: You may be play with CoreText, check the glyphs and override `drawText:`, but I'd say that's not a simple solution in either case.

Comment: @Larme, I also think it's kind of tricky and not so simple.

Comment: Note tested, but just found this: https://github.com/jrturton/NSString-Glyphs With the `UIBezierPath`, you may find the parts where you want to add extra color.

Comment: @Larme, thanks. I think this one may help. But it's still quite tricky.

Comment: I will say that even with the bezierpath this will not be doable because that is just not what fonts are made for, there is no information present that states where closed areas inside a letter are.